# ElasticSearch get documents with max value after group by

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We want to create a search query for ElastichSearch to

- group documents by `attestationIdentification`
- and then for each group get all the documents that have the largest `attestationSituationNbr` (there can be multiple documents within each group).

**Question**

When launching the query below I get buckets for each `attestationIdentification`, with the max value of `attestationIdentification` in `theMax`.

However, is it possible to get the documents immediately? Like with some kind of `top_hits`? Or do I really have to launch another search using these results?

Also, is it possible to do this using NEST.ElasticSearch?

**Simple example data:**

```
{
 "attestationIdentification" : 1,
 "attestationSituationNbr" : 20
},

{
 "attestationIdentification" : 1,
 "attestationSituationNbr" : 21
},

{
 "attestationIdentification" : 2,
 "attestationSituationNbr" : 30
}
```

**My Query**

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "yourGroup": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "attestationIdentification",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "theMax": {
          "max": {
            "field": "attestationSituationNbr"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

The result is the max value for each group, however, I would like to get the documents with this max value:

```
...
"aggregations": {
   "yourGroup": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
     "buckets": [
       {
         "key": 1,
         "doc_count": 4,
         "theMax": { "value": 21 }
       },
       {
         "key": 2,
         "doc_count": 2,
         "theMax": { "value": 30 }
       }
    ...
```

Comment: did you try using top_hits?

Answer (score 2):

Use `top_hits` like:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "yourGroup": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "attestationIdentification",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "theMax": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": "1",
            "sort": {
              "attestationSituationNbr": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However this does not achieve what I want. As I said, after the "group by" I can have more than 1 document per group with an "attestationSituationNbr" equal to the max value. By using "top_hits" size 1 we only take 1 result but it can be multiple (we don't know how many).